# Exchange 2013, Using a User Principle Name to have multiple domains

Tags: exchange, windows-server-2012, exchange-2013

I currently have a dedicated Exchange Server 2013 running on Windows Server 2012.  I currently have a single domain controller.  Everything is working on my primary domain xxxxxx.info .  I added a second domain through a UPN yyyyyy.com .  I also added it as a second domain.  I am able to receive mail on both addresses to a single mailbox. I was going to create a new user account so I can send from both domains.  For example: user1@xxxxxx.info and user1@xxxxxx.com and I can just set the To by adding a send as.  Unfortunately both email addresses share the same alias (user1).  Therefore I cannot create a new alias for the new .com domain.  What work around can you suggest to allow the alias to have multiple send as addresses.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I just set up a shared account in ECP and set it to forward to my other address. Works fine.